Why apt package want to remove seemingly unrelated packages
Im want to install qt5dxcb-plugin to try and run a program that is complaining about xbc [hoping that package will do it..]
could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

but apt tells me it will remove:
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libmlt++7 libmlt7 libopencv-contrib406 libopencv-highgui406 libqt5opengl5
  libqt5printsupport5 libqt5test5 libqt5webengine5 libqt5webenginecore5
  libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5xml5 melt python3-pyqt5.qtopengl
  python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine qutebrowser qutebrowser-qtwebengine shotcut virtualbox-7.0

virtualbox? pretty sure that's gonna break virtualbox...
shotcut?      why?
Can this be avoided?
Is there a way to check which programs depend on those packages staged to be removed?
